# Keep video playing when app goes to the background and show player controller in the notification

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Want this feature in flutter (android/IOS)

I want to keep the video playing when an app goes to the background and shows a player controller in the notification.

Is  this possible?

Comment: Did you find any solution @karan-singla?

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this library https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio with the latest version **0.9.21**. It's quite easy to configure though some features are still experimental e.g Simultaneous downloading+caching,  Background play which are here [Experimental features](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio#experimental-features). Overall it works for me.